Post-pocalyptic story featuring a dome (dome city?) and a robot zoo
Please help me identify a story. I haven't read it or watched, and unfortunately I don't remember if it was an anime or not, but I believe I stumbled upon it about the time I looked Ergo Proxy on wikipedia. I think the story is set on Earth, in the future. Humanity is almost extinct and the remaining humans live in a dome city, and there might be other domes in the world. Outside of the dome the world is in a post-apocalyptic condition. The story most likely follows a girl, and I don't remember exactly, but she was somewhat interested in animals that lived in that dome, but then she discoveres that all animals are in fact robots, because real ones went extinct many years ago. I also vaguely remember some elemental or technical incident that happened afterwards, but I'm not sure what it was. I apologise for this undetailed explanation. The story I'm looking for MIGHT also be described in one of the existing questions (link below). Please help and thank you in advance!
SF short story about a dome with a kid and a robot

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  If you're not sure if the other question matches, how will you be able to tell if the correct answer is posted here?

https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9580832-the-boy-at-the-end-of-the-world is suggested as an answer

I'm sure I will recognize it when I see that wiki page once again. Facts elude me, but I remember the structure like a word on the tip of my tongue
@DavidW

The closest thing to a match I can think of from anime is Kemono Friends.  That has the zoo, the girl protagonist, the post-apocalyptic setting, and robot (sort-of; it's not clear) animals. But the entire action is in the area of the zoo, which is the size of a wild-animal park with habitats. If there is a separate dome or other location with humans, it isn't shown.  The 2017 version was normal hand-drawn animation. There was a 2019 "Season 2" that was pretty much a CGI remake rather than a new story. I watched only a couple of episodes of the remake, so maybe it had an expanded plot eventually.
